# Will garbage memory show up as taking space in java?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, garbage, collect

I'm wondering if garbage memory that hasen't been collected yet will show up as taking space if I do the following:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long usedMemory = rt.totalMemory() - rt.freeMemory();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Will this show up ? Well ... try it.

Comment: if objects were not collected and cleared, they will necessary be considered as not freed.

Comment: Ok thank you davidxxx